# Active Admin view to PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, activeadmin

I'm starting to develop in Ruby on Rails recently, therefore I consider myself beginner.

I'm testing the Active Admin gem ( http://activeadmin.info/ ) and I found a problem when export a view to PDF.

In the official documentation says how to customize the download links (http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages.html, it is at the end of the document) but does not work for me.

When I put the following line of code:

```
Mymodel ActiveAdmin.register do
  index: download_links => [: pdf]
end
```

The result is a link to localhost:3000/admin/mymodel.pdf and the following error displays: "Failed to load PDF document".

two questions:

1. What do you suggest?
2. Could you give an example?

I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was questioned for a while ago, but I'm adding an example that is a little more specific to ActiveAdmin for the future searchers as @user2163649's answer is a more general approach.

First we need to make it clear that ActiveAdmin does not support PDF export out of the box. You need to implement it yourself.

I picked up WickedPDF gem for PDF creation, but you can choose from [several other options](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/pdf_generation) such as Prawn, Pdfkit, etc according to your needs and limits.

```ruby
# Gemfile
gem 'wicked_pdf'
```

```ruby
# app/admin/pages.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Page do
  controller do
    # if you want /admin/pages/12345.pdf
    def show
      super do |format|
        format.pdf { render(pdf: "page-#{resource.id}.pdf") }
      end
    end
  end

  # if you want /admin/pages/12345/pdf, pdf_admin_page_path(@page)
  member_action :pdf, method: :get do
    render(pdf: "page-#{resource.id}.pdf")
  end
end
```

```erb
# app/views/admin/order_items/show.pdf.erb
<h1>page <%= resource.id %></h1>
<p><%= resource.body %></p>
```

```erb
# app/views/admin/order_items/show.html.erb
<h1>page <%= resource.id %></h1>
<p><%= resource.body %></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

try prawn gem.. I think it is the most excellent ruby library for generating PDF documents..

ex.

in your index

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    pdf = SalePdf.new(@sales)
    send_data pdf.render, filename: "Daily_Sales_Report, :disposition => "inline"
  end
end
```

sale_pdf.rb

```
class SalePdf < Prawn::Document
  text "sample pdf"
end
```

github:
https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn

Comment: @user2163649, I assume you mean index under app/controllers, but ActiveAdmin has it own index method.

Comment: I've add an answer which is more specific to ActiveAdmin.