# ActiveAdmin export as {PDF, XML} custom links for each page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, prawn

I am using Rails 3.2.8 with activeadmin. The problem I am facing is if I set up custom links for [exporting](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages.html) as pdf(using Prawn gem) or xml as,

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project do
  index :download_links => [:pdf, :xml]
  controller do
    ...
  end

  index do
    column "Icon" do |project|
    # And a couple of other columns.
  end
end
```

I end up losing all the custom columns(e.g. Icon) on the page.

I only want  the export as PDF option on current page and hence I did not set up the global activeadmin initializer with download links for XML and PDF.

So, could anyone help me figure out how I could have the download link for pdf only in my  current activeadmin page.

Comment: AFAIK, ActiveAdmin doesn't support PDF export out of the box. Could you tell me what is your configurations for pdf?

Comment: Yes you are right about that, I created a custom PDF controller to render PDF files as I wanted to be able to export given page as a PDF file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Active Admin view to PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411011/active-admin-view-to-pdf)

Comment: I've shared my approach at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25841863/157816 Please take a look at this and share yours if you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@sanghyun-park
This is my activeadmin controller,

```
  controller do
    def index
      index! do |format|
        format.html
        format.pdf {
         pdf = ProjectPdf.new(@projects)
         send_data pdf.render, filename: "Project_status.pdf",
                               disposition: "inline"
        }
      end
    end
  end
```

And this is the model I have to render PDF documents,

```
class ProjectPdf < Prawn::Document
    def initialize(projects)
        super(top_margin: 50)
        text "Summary of Projects" , :style => :bold, :size => 20
        proj_array = [[ "Company Name" , "Project Name", "Project State", 
     "Latest Upload"]]
        projects.each do |item|
              proj_array << [ 
                item.company.name.nil? ? "" : item.company.name,
                item.name,
                item.project_state.nil? ? "" : item.project_state.name, 
                item.updated_at.strftime("%m/%y/%d \n %l:%M %p")
              ]
        end
    end
```

Your [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25841863/157816) looks more concise and easier for exporting page to PDF in activeadmin.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. I haven't used Prawn. Prawn seems to give more precise control of PDF layout. I think WickedPDF is more easier to use as it converts plain HTML documents to PDF.